# Displaying show/hide content with a button and an .active css class

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a testimonial section on a wordpress site where there is an "expand" button to show the full testimonial quote. I want the text in the button to change to "collapse" after it is clicked. I also need to add a class to the div wraper so I can implement custom css styling when the button is active. I need this pasted three times. The problem is it fails after the first testimonial.

I have this working with the code below, with it duplicated three times (for three different testimonials) and it works on a basic html document. But when I implement it in a wordpress site by pasting the code, only the first testimonial totally works. The other two do show/hide my inner div element, but they won't insert the .active class or change the text of the button to "collapse"

Both of the second testimonials give a

***"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null"*** in the console.

So for example, here are two out of three of my testimonials I want to show. I have to change the ID's on them to avoid the javascript conflict.

```js
function showhide() {
  var content = document.getElementById('hidden-content');
  var wrap = document.getElementById('testimonial-wrap');
  var btn = document.getElementById('button1');

  if (content.style.display === 'none') {
    content.style.display = 'block';
    wrap.style.background = 'grey';
    btn.innerHTML = 'COLLAPSE';
    wrap.classList.add('active');
  } else {
    content.style.display = 'none';
    wrap.style.background = 'white';
    btn.innerHTML = 'EXPAND';
    wrap.classList.remove('active');
  }
}

function showhide2() {
  var content2 = document.getElementById('hidden-content2');
  var wrap2 = document.getElementById('testimonial-wrap2');
  var btn2 = document.getElementById('button2');

  if (content2.style.display === 'none') {
    content2.style.display = 'block';
    wrap2.style.background = 'grey';
    btn2.innerHTML = 'COLLAPSE';
    wrap2.classList.add('active');
  } else {
    content2.style.display = 'none';
    wrap2.style.background = 'white';
    btn2.innerHTML = 'EXPAND';
    wrap2.classList.remove('active');
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="testimonial-wrap" style="background-color: white;">
  <div id="testimonial">
    above testimonial content
    <div id="hidden-content" style="display: none;">
      <p>"hidden content”</p>
    </div>
    <button id="button1" onclick="showhide()">EXPAND</button>
  </div>
</div>


<div id="testimonial-wrap2" style="background-color: white;">
  <div id="testimonial">
    above testimonial content
    <div id="hidden-content2" style="display: none;">
      <p>"hidden content.”</p>
    </div>
    <button id="button2" onclick="showhide2()">EXPAND</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I edited your question to convert your code into a runnable snippet, and it seems to work perfectly. Can you reproduce the error in the snippet?

Comment: Oddly enough it works for me on a static html file. It's when I pace it into an active wordpress install that I have issues...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for. You can do it much easier with jQuery & a small amout of code.

I didn't use `display: none` as I want to add the transition to the action. (transition won't work with `display: none`)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".toggle-button").on("click", function() {
    $(this).closest(".testimonial-wrap").toggleClass("active");
  });
});
```

```css
.testimonial-wrap {
  background-color: #C1C1C1;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.testimonial-wrap.active {
  background-color: #0095FF
}

.hidden-content {
  height: 0px;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
}

.active .hidden-content {
  height: 100px;
  visibility: visible;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

button {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="testimonial-wrap">
  <div id="testimonial">
    <p>above testimonial content</p>
    <div class="hidden-content">
      <p>"hidden content”</p>
    </div>
    <button id="button1" class="toggle-button">EXPAND</button>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="testimonial-wrap">
  <div id="testimonial">
    <p>above testimonial content</p>
    <div class="hidden-content">
      <p>"hidden content.”</p>
    </div>
    <button id="button2" class="toggle-button">EXPAND</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is great! I love that I can duplicate the html multiple times using the same div ID tags and I don't have to add extra lines of javascript and css to support it!

Comment: Follow up question... I actually need to target the "testimonial-wrap div in order to add the ".active" class to it. I need to set styling to the background of the whole wrapper div on active. And in the real-world example it'll likely have more or less divs in-between the wrapper and the final hidden text. Is there a way with jquery to add a class to specific IDs? or to use the "$(this).parent" option to look upward in the html and apply the .active class to the first instance it sees? I tried adding that but it didn't work. -- $(this).parent().find(".testimonial-wrap").toggleClass("active");

Comment: Also for some reason the end of the quote shows ".â€" for me instead of the end quote symbol. It works fine on here so I'm not really sure why :/

Comment: hi @K.Dustin Based on your follow up questions, you can use the function `$(this).parent(".testimonial-wrap")` to find exactly the parent with such class or ID.

Comment: I updated the solution to match with your needs. I mistaken that we must use `$(this).closest(".testimonial-wrap")` instead of `parent()`

Comment: You're incredible thank you so much! After hours of searching on my own (I forgot to check back here) I actually came up with the same solution. Through an If Then statement I also added in the ability to change the text of the button. I never would have figured this out without your help!

Comment: I have a some-what similar but different situation I'm struggling with here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53877138/grid-with-multiple-show-hide-elements-and-multiple-rows If you're able to help with that one too that'd be freaking incredible!